# Can I use my Ubuntu laptop as a Wifi Repeater?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

My iPod doesn't receive the signal from the router whereas my laptop does(50%).

I am wondering if there is a way iPod can be configured to receive signal from the Laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a wireless access point / another wireless router to the laptop, then connect the iPod to that.

Or use another wireless network card and run a DHCP server on the laptop.

Comment: I don't think there will be a solution that does not involve having another wireless device. The laptop must be both a dhcp client and a dhcp server, and I doubt a single device could do this. (Definitely easier to use 2, anyawy)

Comment: Yea, I have another Router at my disposal. Thanks.